# py2exe installation error Could not load Python

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I try installing py2exe. I am using Python 2.7 and also downloaded from sourceforge the correct installer for py2exe. Unfortunately, when I try to install it, the installer gives me following error:

```
*** Could not load Python ***
```

I could not find a solution for this error.

I am using Anaconda2 and the installer also shows me the correct directory, where the python.exe is.

Answer (score 0):

For me a re-installation of Python and a reboot resolved it